# How to query a document based on a field within a referenced subdocument with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Having two models: `Supplier` and `SupplierType` - the `supplier_type` field on the `Supplier` model holds an `ObjectId` reference to the relevant `supplier_type` document.

I need to retrieve all `Suppliers` where `Supplier.supplier_type.name` is "Bakers"

`Supplier` schema (trimmed for brevity):

```
const supplierSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 255,
  },
  ...
  supplier_type: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'SupplierType' },
});
```

`Supplier Type` schema:

```
const supplierTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 50,
  },
  ...
});
```

A typical `Supplier` document - where `Supplier.supplier_type.populate()` has been used:

```
{
            ...
            "_id": "5e9604d45c18767097e00059",
            "name": "Benny's",
            "supplier_type": {
                "suppliers": [
                    "5e9604d45c18767097e00059"
                ],
                "_id": "5e8f7e2eca14f14e36785b8d",
                "name": "Bakers",
                "createdAt": "2020-04-09T19:57:34.731Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-04-14T18:48:21.853Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            ...
        },
```

Query:

```
const supplier = await SupplierType.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          name: 'Bakers',
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'supplier',
          localField: 'pk',
          foreignField: 'id',
          as: 'supplier',
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          supplier: 1,
        },
      },
    ])
    console.log('LOG: Supplier: ', supplier);
    if (!supplier) return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Supplier not found', code: 609 });

    res.send({ data: supplier });
```

Returns:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5e8f7e2eca14f14e36785b8d",
            "supplier": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: IF i m not wrong... you are trying to get the ids from supplier_type collection where name is "baker" and then search the supplier collection with where supplier_type matches the result ids right??

Comment: I'm trying to return all Suppliers where `Supplier.supplier_type.name` is "Bakers"

Comment: Shouldn't this aggregation has a `$lookup` stage, if it takes data from 2 different collections? Can you place more example docs from Mongo? What does the `supplier` variable stores w/o `$match` stage?

Comment: @AlexZeDim - as you ask - without the `$match` stage, will return all `Supplier` documents

Comment: @DaveDODea with the `supplier_type` as embedded, like an example, or `unwind`  version of it?

Comment: Please see the 3rd snippet above in my question - there is a an example with the `supplier_type` embedded

Comment: Yea, I have seen it before, that the point, that if you are having `{ $unwind: '$supplier_type' }` it shouldn't look that in the 3-rd snippet.

Comment: No - that is an example of what a document would look like with `Supplier.supplier_type.populate()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212109/discussion-between-alexzedim-and-davedodea).

Comment: My question is, how to query the `Supplier` document  based on a field-value contained in the referenced `supplier_type` document